# How to set react hook form default values when using Controller with custom components

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

**What I'm trying to do:**

- Provide default values to my custom controlled rhf components and have them update like an rhf uncontrolled component.
- Better understand how Controller sets default values so I can troubleshoot.

**My problem:**

- I can only set default values with a rhf uncontrolled component as [shown in the docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset). For example, by creating a `defaultValues` object with each input's default value then calling `reset({...defaultValues})` in a `useEffect` on page load.
- I don't understand how rhf passes/sets default values with `Controller`

Examples:

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-glitter-q8vmpj?file=/src/RegistrationForm.tsx)

```
// Parent form component (RegistrationForm.tsx)

      // set up form default values
      const defaultValues = {
        standardRadio: "mint",
        registerRadio: "supercross"
      };
    
      // fill in default values on load
      useEffect(() => {
        reset({ ...defaultValues });
      }, []);

 // DOESN'T WORK: Can't set the default value of WrapperRadioGroup 
      <WrapperRadioGroup
        name="standardRadio"
        groupLabel="This is a radio group label"
        control={control}
        style="standard"
        defaultValue=" "
        options={[
          { value: "orange", label: "Orange ice cream" },
          { value: "mint", label: "Mint ice cream" },
          { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate ice cream" },
          { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla ice cream" }
        ]}
      />

// Default value set properly using the following uncontrolled component
  <input
    {...register("registerRadio")}
    id="registerRadio1"
    type="radio"
    value="motogp"
  />
  <label htmlFor="registerRadio1">Moto GP</label>
...
  <input
    {...register("registerRadio")}
    id="registerRadio4"
    type="radio"
    value="islemantt"
  />
  <label htmlFor="registerRadio4">Isle of Man TT</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. When using Controller there's no need to pass a `defaultValue` prop on the parent component as doing so will override the value used by RHF's Controller. RHF takes the value you set up in your `defaultValues` object and then make that the current `value` for the input.

Example:

1. Set the default values for all of your inputs via an object. (Key: `input's name` value: `input default value`).

```
    const defaultValues = {
       standardRadio: "mint",
       registerRadio: "supercross"
     }
```

2. Use reset() to update the form inputs. [See documentation.](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset)

```
    useEffect(() => {
      reset({ ...defaultValues });
     }, []);
```

3. Don't pass a defaultValue prop to the controlled component. If you do it will override RHF Controller's value.

```
     <WrapperRadioGroup
        name="standardRadio"
        groupLabel="This is a radio group label"
        control={control}
        style="standard"
    =>  defaultValue=" " // !! DON'T PASS A DEFAULTVALUE PROP. OVERRIDES RHF's CONTROLLER
        options={[
          { value: "orange", label: "Orange ice cream" },
          { value: "mint", label: "Mint ice cream" },
          { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate ice cream" },
          { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla ice cream" }
        ]}
      />
```

4. If you need the default value in the input's controlled component then access it via `props.value`